Kubernetes (K8S) ERROR - couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s": Service Unavailable
currently facing some issue with  Kubernetes clusters (1 master node, 1 worker node setup) in Ubuntu. earlier nodes are listed, unfortunately now none of kubectl commands against cluster was working.
When executing the command kubectl get pods, I'm encountering the following error message:
E1016 10:49:01.129636    4029 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s": Service Unavailable
E1016 10:49:01.139686    4029 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s": Service Unavailable
Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable

ERROR while executing kubectl version command:
Client Version: v1.30.5
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable

Troubleshooting further - ERROR while executing kubectl get nodes -v=10 command:
I1016 10:49:31.010826    4037 loader.go:395] Config loaded from file:  /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
I1016 10:49:31.011732    4037 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.30.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/74e84a9" 'https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s'
I1016 10:49:31.013627    4037 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:10.57.183.219:3128 succeed
I1016 10:49:31.015587    4037 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s  in 3 milliseconds
I1016 10:49:31.015826    4037 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 1 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 3 ms
I1016 10:49:31.016029    4037 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
E1016 10:49:31.016268    4037 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s": Service Unavailable
I1016 10:49:31.016475    4037 cached_discovery.go:120] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s": Service Unavailable
I1016 10:49:31.016748    4037 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.30.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/74e84a9" 'https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s'
I1016 10:49:31.018193    4037 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:10.57.183.219:3128 succeed
I1016 10:49:31.019721    4037 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s  in 2 milliseconds
I1016 10:49:31.020607    4037 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 1 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 2 ms
I1016 10:49:31.020882    4037 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
E1016 10:49:31.021213    4037 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s": Service Unavailable
I1016 10:49:31.021363    4037 cached_discovery.go:120] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s": Service Unavailable
I1016 10:49:31.021384    4037 shortcut.go:103] Error loading discovery information: Get "https://poc_master_node:6443/api?timeout=32s": Service Unavailable

Already KUBECONFIG environment variable export done (both master and worker node):
echo $KUBECONFIG
/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

result for kubectl config view command:
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://poc_master_node:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-adm
  name: kubernetes-adm@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-adm@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-adm
  user:
    client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
    client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED

Here are the details:
Kub version: Kubernetes 1.30 - K8S
OS:  Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
followed this blog steps to set up K8S cluster
Already checked this question as well.
Can anyone able to provide guidance to resolve this?

Refer to this blog by Nir Shtein which might be helpful to resolve your issue.
